# invalid label on firefox javascript error

Tags: javascript

Can somebody find out whats going wrong with this piece of code, I get Invalid label error on my firebug console.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var a = function(){
       this.prop1:"value1", //Error here
       this.prop2:"value2"
    }
        var b = new a();
 </script>
```

Comment: If you are wondering what a label is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/Label

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a = function() {
    this.prop1 = "value1";
    this.prop2 = "value2";
};
var b = new a();
```

The `:` is only used when using the object literal syntax. For example, if every object of type `a` will have these properties, you might set them in the prototype instead:

```
var a = function() {
    // ...
};
a.prototype = {
    prop1: "value1",
    prop2: "value2"
};

var b = new a();
alert(b.prop1); // alerts "value1"
```

Note that the effect is often the same but the meaning is different in important ways (read up on prototypes, the `in` operator, and `Object.hasOwnProperty()` among other things).

Answer (score 2):

You're not defining an object, use = instead:

```
var a = function() {
    this.prop1 = "value1";
    this.prop2 = "value2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be '=' not ':'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a = function(){
      this.prop1="value1", //Error here
      this.prop2="value2"
    }
    var b = new a();
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Should be like this. You should use equal sign because you are not defining an object, you are in a function. And should use ; at the end of line not ,

```
   var a = function(){
      this.prop1 = "value1"; //Error here
      this.prop2 = "value2";
  }
  var b = new a();
```